# My user sign-in works fine, my admin sign-in doesn't work at all

Tags: php, html

Hi this is just a small project, i'm doing for my self development. 
I've created user sign-in and i tried making a sign in for admin for "admin control panel".

Once I press submit after typing in the details it displays message "Email and Password not found"

User details are stored in the same database as admin, I do not understand why it doesn't work?

This is the html code for sign-in:

Admin sign-in

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-3">Admin Sign In</h1>
        <form action="admin_action.php" method="post">
        <label for="uname"><b>Email</b></label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required><br>
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" required><br><br>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>        
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the php code:

admin_action.php :

```
<?php # PROCESS LOGIN ATTEMPT.

# Check form submitted.
if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' )
{
  # Open database connection.
  require ( 'includes/connect_db.php' ) ;

  # Get connection, load, and validate functions.
  require ( 'admin_tools.php' ) ;

  # Check login.
  list ( $check, $data ) = validate ( $link, $_POST[ 'email' ], $_POST[ 'pass' ] ) ;

  # On success set session data and display logged in page.
  if ( $check )  
  {
    # Access session.
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[ 'admin_id' ] = $data[ 'admin_id' ] ;
    load ( 'adminpanel.php' ) ;
  }
  # Or on failure set errors.
  else { $errors = $data; } 

  # Close database connection.
 #mysqli_close( $link ) ; 
}

# Continue to display login page on failure.
include ( 'adminlogin.php' ) ;

?>
```

and admin_tools.php code:

```
<?php # LOGIN HELPER FUNCTIONS.

# Function to load specified or default URL.
function load( $page = 'adminlogin.php' )
{
  # Begin URL with protocol, domain, and current directory.
  $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . dirname( $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ) ;

  # Remove trailing slashes then append page name to URL.
  $url = rtrim( $url, '/\\' ) ;
  $url .= '/' . $page ;

  # Execute redirect then quit. 
  header( "Location: $url" ) ; 
  exit() ;
}

# Function to check email address and password. 
function validate( $link, $email = '', $pwd = '')
{
  # Initialize errors array.
  $errors = array() ; 

  # Check email field.
  if ( empty( $email ) ) 
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your email address.' ; } 
  else  { $e = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link, trim( $email ) ) ; }

  # Check password field.
  if ( empty( $pwd ) ) 
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your password.' ; } 
  else { $p = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link, trim( $pwd ) ) ; }

  # On success retrieve admin_id from 'admin' database.
  if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
  {
    $q = "SELECT admin_id FROM admin WHERE email='$email' AND pass=SHA1('$pass')" ;  
    $r = mysqli_query ( $link, $q ) ;
    if ( @mysqli_num_rows( $r ) == 1 ) 
    {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ;
      return array( true, $row ) ; 
    }
    # Or on failure set error message.
    else { $errors[] = 'Email address and password not found.' ; }
  }
  # On failure retrieve error message/s.
  return array( false, $errors ) ; 
}
```

[databate table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKnK6.png)

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: ___Doesn't work?___ Is not a very helpful description! Do you get errors? What does happen?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Once I type in the admin email and pass, it displays a message that admin and password were not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHA1 generates a 40 byte hash, your pass column is defined as VARCHAR(30). Thats not large enough so the hash wont match the value on the database.

Define it as VARCHAR(256) then even if you decide to use a better hash algo the column will be large enough for the hash

Comment: Hi, still doesn't work I've defined it as VARCHAR(256) and it still displays that email and password were not found.

Comment: Did you SHA1 the password when you stored it?

Comment: I didnt SHA1 the password, now it works! Thank you sir!